# Solve in $\mathbb Z^3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be integer numbers. Solve the following equation.
>   $$x^2+y^2+z^2=45(xy+xz+yz)$$

My trying.

It's a quadratic equation of $z$ and we need $\Delta=n^2$ for an integer $n$,

but it gives a very ugly expression.

Thank you!

Comment: Here is what I have so far: we can notice that $$x^2+y^2+z^2 = (x+y+z)^2 + 2(xy+xz+yz)$$
Then, we can write the above equation as 
$$(x+y+z)^2=47(xy+xz+yz)$$
Now we know that $x+y+z = 47n$ and $xy+yz+zx=47n^2$. We can also notice at this point that $x, y,$ and $z$ must all have the same parity.

Comment: Maybe the following can help: $(x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2=88(xy+xz+yz)$

Comment: Yes! The infinite descent helps. Thanks all!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Can you post your solution ?

Comment: Michael, I am also curious to see your solution.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/225781/fricke-klein-method-for-isotropic-ternary-quadratic-forms/225995#225995

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  good, this time when i wrote an at sign and the letter m, it showed me your entire user name and allowed me to click on it, so the system could fill in the at sign followed by your entire name. Thanks for showing the answer you had in mind. I was not made aware of it by the system, and just found it on my own this morning (California time).  I am unsure about the final step.

Answer (score 3):

Did some informal checking. This one appears to be isotropic in $\mathbb Q_2$ and $\mathbb Q_3.$ It is definitely  anisotropic in $\mathbb Q_{11}$ and $\mathbb Q_{47}.$

I had done this before. There are integer solutions ($x,y,z$ not all zero) to
$$ A(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = B (yz + zx + xy)  $$
with $A,B > 0$ and $\gcd(A,B) = 1$  and $B > A$ if and only if both
$$ B - A = r^2 + 3 s^2 $$ and
$$   B + 2 A = u^2 + 3 v^2 $$

You have
$$   45 - 1 = 44 $$
and
$$ 45 + 2 = 47 $$
both of which are $2 \pmod 3$ and cannot be so written.  See
[Find a solution: $3(x^2+y^2+z^2)=10(xy+yz+zx)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134075/find-a-solution-3x2y2z2-10xyyzzx)

Proving necessity: defining
$$ u = -x-y+2z, \; \; \; v = -x+y, \; \; \; w = x+y+z,  $$ we get diagonalization
$$  12 g = (2A+B) u^2 + 3 (2A+B) v^2 -4(B-A) w^2.  $$
Then we use the theorem of Legendre on indefinite ternaries

[Proof of Legendre's theorem on the ternary quadratic form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27471/proof-of-legendres-theorem-on-the-ternary-quadratic-form)

And, there are no nontrivial solutions to

$$   47 u^2 + 3 \cdot 47 v^2 -4\cdot 44 w^2.  $$
$$   47 u^2 + 141 v^2 -176 w^2.  $$

To be specific, if
$$  47 u^2 + 3 \cdot 47 v^2 -4\cdot 44 w^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {11^2},  $$
then all 
$$ u,v,w \equiv 0 \pmod {11}. $$
As a result, there can be no solutions with $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1,$ hence no nonzero solutions.

If there are any solutions, you get infinitely many by Vieta Jumping, similar to the Markoff numbers $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3xyz.$ Similarly, one may rule out any solutions. I am on the phone, if you cannot work it out I can do something later  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number

Comment: How do you know that these conditions most hold ?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal it was pretty long. See my answers from a couple of years ago http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134075/find-a-solution-3x2y2z2-10xyyzzx

Comment: @SandeepSilwal I added in enough material for this proof; it suffices to consider $\pmod {121}$ to show that there can be no solution at all; you could call that infinite descent.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal you could also use the prime $47,$ more or less the same.

Comment: @Will Jagy I used the following primitive reasoning. Let $x=11x_1+r$, $y=11y_1+r$ and $z=11z_1+r$, where $\{x_1,y_1,z_1,r\}\subset\mathbb Z$ and $0\leq r\leq10$. Hence, $\sum\limits_{cyc}(11x_1+r)^2=45\sum\limits_{cyc}(11x_1+r)(11y_1+r)$, which gives that $r^2\vdots11$ and $r=0$. I think using of number $47$ is an easier way.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg thanks. I don't usually write anything with the "cyc" subscript or a vertical thing with three dots, give me a minute.

Answer (score 2):

For  Will Jagy, I am sorry!

Let $x-y=a$, $y-z=b$ and $z-x=c$.

Hence, $a^2+b^2+c^2\vdots11$ and $a+b+c=0$.

Thus, $a^2+ab+b^2\vdots11$, which says that $a\vdots11$ and $b\vdots11$ and $x\equiv y\equiv z(\mod11)$,

which gives $x\vdots11$, $y\vdots11$ and $z\vdots11$ (if $x\equiv y\equiv z\equiv r(\mod11)$ then $r^2\vdots11$).

Id est,  an infinite descent ends this problem.

Done!

Comment: @Will Jagy What do you think? You asked. Say something.

Comment: I just found this. Not sure why I was not notified that I had a comment from you, but that sometimes happens. i will take a look.

Comment: Not sure about the final step. You do get $x \equiv y \equiv z \equiv r \pmod {11}$ for some $r.$ Then the part about $1$ and $45$ says $3 r^2 \equiv 45 \cdot 3r^2 \pmod {11},$ or $44 \cdot 3 r^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {11}$ which need not say anything as $44$ is divisible by $11$

Comment: In any case, thanks for replying and writing this up. Note that a comment under my answer (or a question of mine) would have worked 99% of the time, while a comment elsewhere may not work, or may be missed owing to the time zone difference. I will fiddle with it some more.